# How to add Treemap chart to plotly-basic.min.js, without adding whole plotly.min.js?

Tags: import, plotly, plotly.js

Since I would like to keep bundle as small as possible, I would prefer to avoid referencing plotly.min.js(which is rather large, several MBs unzipped, over 1MB gzipped), and would rather add just treemap to the already referenced plotly-basic.min.js, if that is possible?

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made custom build like this:

```js
import plotly from 'plotly.js/lib/core';
import pie from 'plotly.js/lib/pie';
import scatter from 'plotly.js/lib/scatter';
import bar from 'plotly.js/lib/bar';
import treemap from 'plotly.js/lib/treemap';

plotly.register([pie, scatter, bar, treemap]);

export default plotly;
```

and it's working perfectly.